# Mysql string index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, text-search

I need a mysql query for text search for name and surname... This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE CONCAT(name,' ',surname) like 'John%'
or CONCAT(name,' ',surname) like '% John%'; --mind the space in second like
```

This query should find "John Fox" and "Fox John" and "John Fox Joe" and "Joe John Fox" and so on.
This works fine, but for big tables I think I should add and index... Am i right? 
I read that btree indexes are useful only for `like 'John%'` syntax and not for `like '% John%'`. So maybe can not be useful to add a new column made of CONCAT(name,' ',surname) for a new index.

I would like to know what is the best approach for this text-search problem.

PS: I'm using innodb tables, so I cannot use fulltext indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should upgrade to mysql 5.6 where `FULLTEXT` is supported on InnoDB.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Some years ago I used fulltext with myisam, I found some trouble with stop words like 'and' 'the' and so on because they were ignored by search engine. My search should includes that words, is this configurable?

Comment: You can change the stopwords for each table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html